# Markdown Editor With Regular Expressions Not Producing Desired Output

Tags: javascript, regex

[Please check out this codepen for a working code example](http://codepen.io/nhuyvan1106/pen/oLaRyZ)

I have two regular expressions

```
//Matches ol:whatever: and turns it into <ol>whatever</ol>
var olRegex = /ol:[\s\r\f\n]?([\s\S\r\f\n]*)[\r\f\n]:/;

//Matches li:whatever: and turns it into <li>whatever</li>
var liRegex = /li:(.*):/gi;
```

If I type

```
ol:
li:This is item 1:
li:This is item 2:
:
```

It will be correctly replaced by this output

```
<ol>
    <li>This is item 1</li>
    <li>This is item 2</li>
</ol>
```

But if I add 2 blocks like this

```
ol:
li:This is item 1:
li:This is item 2:
:
ol:
li:This is item 1:
li:This is item 2:
:
```

It does not produce what I expects, it produces this output instead

```
<ol>
    <li>This is item 1</li>
    <li>This is item 2</li>
: // I want the olRegex to stop matching here

ol:
    <li>This is item 1</li>
    <li>This is item 2</li>
</ol>
```

I want it to output

```
<ol>
    <li>This is item 1</li>
    <li>This is item 2</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <li>This is item 1</li>
    <li>This is item 2</li>
</ol>
```

My `olRegex` does not include the `g` flag, why doesn't it stop matching when it encounters that first `:` that stays on its own line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `var olRegex = /ol:[\s\r\f\n]?([\s\S\r\f\n]*)[\r\f\n]:/;` the use of `*` will read characters matching `[\s\S\r\f\n]` as far as it until it finds the last possible `[\r\f\n]:` (greedy).

Instead of `*` you may use `*?` which attempts to match those characters as few times as possible (lazy).

By doing this with the `g` flag you will end up with the desired match groups.

Comment: Man. I had been desperately waiting for this answer. Thank you a bunch